# How to focus a form input field when page loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails 3 application, I have a view haml file with a form like following:

```
= form_for(:car, :url => cars_path) do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :carname
  %p  
    = f.text_field :carname /focus here
  %p
    = f.label :carnr
  %p
    = f.text_field :carnr
  %p
    = f.submit
```

I would like the **input field** `= f.text_field :carname` is in **focus** when the page is loaded.

How to do it? Is it necessary to use jquery? or is there any Rails way to do the focus?

Comment: it would be good to know you made this work and accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 62):

it isn't necessary to use jquery, but it is necessary to use javascript *if you're not using HTML5* but you will have to do with jquery or javascript for now:

```
document.getElementById('carname').focus();
```

or

```
$("carname").focus();
```

[with HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)

```
= f.text_field :carname, :autofocus => true
```

There is one caveat on the HTML5 approach: the field that you autofocus does NOT
get a focus() event so any CSS styling that you do through onfocus doesn't happen.

Answer (score 16):

### Use `autofocus`.

**NOTE: HTML5 Only. See [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus).**

```
= form_for(:car, :url => cars_path) do |f|
  %p
   = f.label :carname
 %p  
   = f.text_field :carname, autofocus: true
 %p
   = f.label :carnr
%p
  = f.text_field :carnr
%p
= f.submit
```